# EventTrigger with Setter in WPF?

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, setter

I have a normal Button and TextBox in a WPF-Window and I want a Template for the Button with a EventTrigger that listens to Button.Click and then sets a boolean-property of the TextBox. No code-behind.

Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger SourceName="MyButton" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <Setter TargetName="MyTextBox" Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
  </EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a sample that sets and clears `Focusable` on a TextBox from an EventTrigger.
Hopefully you can adapt this example to your situation.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox 
        x:Name="tb"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Text="Here is some sample text">
    </TextBox>
    <Button 
        x:Name="btnFocusTrue"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Content="Set True">
    </Button>
    <Button 
        x:Name="btnFocusFalse"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Content="Set False">
    </Button>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnFocusTrue">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="FocusTrueStoryboard">
                <Storyboard >
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="tb"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Focusable)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                            KeyTime="00:00:01"
                            Value="True" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnFocusFalse">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="FoucsFalseStoryboard">
                <Storyboard >
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="tb"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Focusable)">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                            KeyTime="00:00:01"
                            Value="False" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ahhh missed the Discrete*KeyFrame-classes... its a solution to my problem but its a lot of xaml for such a simple task... i wish there where a shorter version

Comment: How can we set the custom dependency property value in the event trigger ??

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [behaviours](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) to achieve your desired outcome:
First, add the reference:

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Afterwards, you can assign a Value to any Property of your choosing using an Interaction Trigger and a [ChangePropertyAction](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/ChangePropertyAction):

```
<Button>
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <b:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

You can also use this to change properties in your DataContext by specifying a TargetObject like so:

```
<b:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding MemberOfYourDataContext}" PropertyName="PropertyOfYourDataContextMember" Value="StaticValueOrBinding"/>
```