# Handling a Button's Click event in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This feels like a terribly basic question but I am sure there is a better way to do this. I have a `Button` in my UI which selects a specific tab and fire a `Command` from the `ViewModel`

Here is the current code (which works fine):

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Button!" Click="OnButtonClick" Command="{Binding WhateverCommand}" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     theTab.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Isn't there any cleaner, XAML-only way to do that UI operation? I was thinking about something like:

```
<Button Content="Button!" Click="OnButtonClick" Command="{Binding WhateverCommand}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
            <Setter TargetName="theTab" Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Trigger>
</Button>
```

But unfortunately it seems like the `EventTrigger` won't support a `Click` event. Why so? I am still sometimes confused with triggers after a few years working in WPF, and this pretty much sums it up. When trying to build that I have an error on the `Setter` line:

```
A value of type 'Setter' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'.
```

Thank you!

**EDIT** since I was ask the XAML structure of my Window, it looks like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Button Content="Button!" Click="OnButtonClick" Command="{Binding WhateverCommand}" />
    </Ribbon>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="theTab" />
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: can you post your complete xaml including the tab you are talking about?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942548/setting-a-property-with-an-eventtrigger) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870214/eventtrigger-with-setter-in-wpf) might be an answer to you... (And also use Button.Click instead of Click)

Comment: It is not relevant to the question itself imo. Do you need it?

Comment: yes. I want to see the hierarchy where button is and where tab is?

Comment: @qqbenq : Wow, this seems unexpectedly... complicated for a simple tab change. Is there any other way than a `storyboard` for achieving such a simple thing? I believe it's actually clearer to use a code-behind handler rather than an animation for this

@nit : updated with a basic XAML skeleton

Comment: @Damascus I agree, it seems awfully complicated, but this is how it can be done :) You can create a storyboard resource, and use it in the Trigger, it will look a little bit simpler.

Comment: Indeed. I'll look into a way to simplify that. Maybe create a specific Storyboard class designed to set a property. Ugh, sometimes WPF just amazes me by how simple stuff can be complicated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There definitely is a better way. With the help of the `Windows.Interactivity` assembly you are able to bind the event source to a singe class, containing only the associated action. With this you can almost do everything you ned.

The action class has to derive from TriggerAction. By overriding the `Invoke`-method you can specify the action.

Despite this scenario it also possible to bind the `EventTrigger` to a command (e.g. relay command), allowing a clean MMVM implementation.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<Button x:Name="button">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger SourceName="button" EventName="Click">
                                <app:MyAction/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

```vb
Public Class MyAction
    Inherits Interactivity.TriggerAction(Of UIElement)

    Protected Overrides Sub Invoke(parameter As Object)
        MsgBox("Clicked")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I updated the code to meet your specific requirements. The `TriggerAction` class now also contains a dependency property, which can be cound to your tab control:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tab"/>
                    <Button x:Name="button">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger SourceName="button" EventName="Click">
                                <app:MyAction Target="{Binding ElementName=tab}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

```vb
Public Class MyAction
    Inherits Interactivity.TriggerAction(Of UIElement)

    Protected Overrides Sub Invoke(parameter As Object)
        DirectCast(Target, TabControl).SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Shared Sub New()
        _targetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Target",
          GetType(UIElement),
          GetType(MyAction),
          New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))
    End Sub

    Private Shared _targetProperty As DependencyProperty
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property TargetProperty As DependencyProperty
        Get
            Return _targetProperty
        End Get
    End Property

    Property Target As UIElement
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(TargetProperty), UIElement)
        End Get
        Set(value As UIElement)
            SetValue(TargetProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Great :-) Please regard that I updated the code to also deal with the TabControl.

Answer (score 9):

Error sums it up. You cannot use `Setter` in `EventTrigger`. If you want to do it in XAML you can use `Storyboard` that will select given tab when button is pressed. Something like this:

```
<Button Content="Click">
   <Button.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
           <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard>
                   <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="theTab" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                       <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                   </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
           </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
   </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Somebody also posted this as a comment, and my concern is: for the sake of simplicity, why would a `Storyboard` with an `Animation` be more simple/clean than a code-behind `EventHandler` ? If this is the only way to do this, I think I'll probably stick to the code-behind way. I'll keep the question open to see if anything else comes up before accepting your answer :) Thank you!

Comment: You're right, in this case, code behind is simpler. The problem is that normal `Trigger` has concept of state so `Setter` can be undone but `EventTrigger` has no such concept so all you can do is start some actions when it happens.

Comment: Oh, so that's why. I'm always confused between all of these `Triggers` possibility. why would those in a `Style` be different! I'll try to work a shorter solution. Maybe by creating a separate `Storyboard` derived class

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce a `bool` property `IsMyTabSelected` to your VM, bind it to `TabItem.IsSelected`:

```
<TabItem x:Name="theTab" IsSelected="{Binding IsMyTabSelected}" >
```

Then you just set this flag in the `WhateverCommand` handler for the `Button`. 
Note: The `IsMyTabSelected` property must implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Then it's not XAML-Only! Also no real point in keeping a `IsMyTabSelected` pure UI property in my ViewModel since that can just be switched in XAML code behind. What's fun is that for such a simple problem, every single solution seems equally not adapted :/

Comment: Not XAML-only, but also no code-behind and simple. Moreover, it is tough (impossible?) to keep `ViewModel` away from 'pure UI' in large project.